# Module './login/servcioprueba1.service"' has no exported member 'prueba'.ts(2305)

Tags: angular, service

i have i service file in angular 8

ng g s servicioprueba1

I import the file as follow

See Block 2

and in this line of the Block

import { prueba } from './servcioprueba1.service';
i get the error << Module '"../extra/login/servcioprueba1.service"' has no exported member 'prueba'.ts(2305) >>

Someone knows, how i can solve the error

NOTE: In other project of the angular 8 the code works fine

Tank You

Block 2

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from  '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from  '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'; 
import { prueba } from './servcioprueba1.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class PageLoginComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private authService: prueba) { }

}
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of the servcioprueba1 service? If is angular 8 then you don't need to declare services in the module, my best guess is that the servcioprueba1 exported class is not named prueba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution, when i do the import, the name of the import must be the same of the service, por example.

If i write

import { prueba } from './seruser.service'; // it´s wrong
But, if i write
import { seruser } from './seruser.service'; // it´s correct

I did not know the name from the import is was important

Answer (score 1):

In your module that the service belongs to, make sure you have it listed as a provider

```
// other imports
import { prueba } from '<path_to_prueba.service.ts>'; 

@NgModule({
    declarations: [<Name_Of_Module>],
    imports: [
        //...
    ],
    providers: [
        //other providers ...
        prueba,
    ],
})
export class <Name_Of_Module> {}
```

and then also the same for the module that `PageLoginComponent` belongs to.

Comment: Hi, tank you for you comment, I am new in angular, i understand that i place the code in the app.module.ts file but, the error is the same.

Comment: In the module that `PageLoginComponent` belongs to, you must also list `prueba` as a provider. Hopefully that is the reason for your error.